# Cannot resolve constructor in Java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I want to create a cloned list. I am using the below code snippet, but my IDE is showing a compilation error as "Cannot resolve constructor" even though `MyClass` has a default constructor.

```
List<MyClass> clonedList = 
    myClassList.stream().map(MyClass::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am new to streams, please help me if my syntax is wrong.

Comment: What does `myClassList` contain?

Comment: its a list of MyClass objects

Comment: ok. is this should be empty constructor just with parameter of same type?

Comment: It shouldn't be empty. You actually have to put code inside that copies the fields from the given object to the new object, handling any deep copies if they are needed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`MyClass::new` will only work in this context if your class has a constructor that takes a single parameter whose type is the type of the elements of the `Stream`. Parameter-less constructor won't work.

```
myClassList.stream().map(MyClass::new)...
```

behaves as

```
myClassList.stream().map(e -> new MyClass(e))...
```

Since `myClassList` is a list of `MyClass` instances, this means a constructor of the following signature will be required in order for the method reference to work -  `MyClass (MyClass other)`.

You can still use the parameter-less constructor with the following lambda expression:

```
myClassList.stream().map(e -> new MyClass())...
```

Of course, that makes little sense, since it ignores the original elements of the `Stream`.

Since your goal is to clone the `List`, you need a copy constructor:

```
public MyClass (MyClass other) {
    // copy the properties of other to this instance
}
```

Comment: I am still confused. My question was how to get cloned list using streams. Example i have List<MyClass> i want to create cloned copy of this list using streams. I know how to write code to make it deep clone but i wanted to know is there something with streams which does that without using copy constructor to achieve deep cloning

Comment: @Rohit the Stream pipeline in your question will work once you add the suggested copy constructor to your class.

Comment: @Rohit either you have a copy constructor or a clone method. There is no magic within the Stream API to allow to clone the unclonable.